# Data Table + delete a row in c# using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a data table and I want to delete a row here is my code it's throwing me an exception

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if ((row["Name"] == "Select a Lookbook") || (row["Name"] == "Create a new Lookbook"))
    {
        row.Delete();
        dt1.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

I even tried outside the if statment and outside forloop still throws me error any idea how to achieve this task this is the exception I get:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
```

Final working Code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Select())
{
    if ((row["Name"] == "Select a Lookbook") ||    (row["Name"] == "Create a new Lookbook"))
    {
        row.Delete();                                       
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely Removing DataRow In ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341580/safely-removing-datarow-in-foreach)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using `dt1.Rows`, use `dt1.Select()`

The goal here is not to use the collection itself, but rather an array of row that is not the `Rows` collection

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted, Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Create a list of rows to delete while iterating over `DataTable.Rows`, then delete them all separately.

Non-LINQ solution:

```
List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if ((row["Name"] == "Select a Lookbook") || 
        (row["Name"] == "Create a new Lookbook"))
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(row);
    }
}
foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
{
    row.Delete();
}
dt1.AcceptChanges();
```

LINQ solution:

```
List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = dt1.Rows.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => (row["Name"] == "Select a Lookbook") || 
                  (row["Name"] == "Create a new Lookbook"))
    .Tolist();
foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
{
    row.Delete();
}
dt1.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: I know it's a very good answer but I have to go with Pierre's answer as I believe easy does it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it when I ran into this issue.

```
            Dim index As Integer = 0
            Dim count As Integer = resultsDT.Rows.Count - 1
            For i As Integer = 0 To count
                If resultsDT.Rows(index).Item("something") = "something" Then
                    resultsDT.Rows(index).Delete()
                    resultsDT.AcceptChanges()
                    index = index - 1
                End If

                index = index + 1
                i = i + 1
            Next
```